# How to update default value of MUI TextField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm finishing up the final steps of my form however I have encounter an issue when trying to display the current name of the user in the `defaultValue` variable of the `TextField` from MUI.

If a value starts on `""`/`null` or basically empty the `defaultValue` will stay empty doesn't matter how many times you update that value from ""/null to something, is there a way to fix that?

I have this:

```
{console.log(tempName)}

<TextField 
required 
margin="dense" 
label='Nombre' 
defaultValue= {tempName} 
onChange={handleChangeName} />
```

`tempName` starts empty but then I update it in a `useEffect` I have that brings the data of the document of the user I'm log in atm, even after having a value the `defaultValue` stays empty/null/"".

[image]

There's something else I did notice though, if you use the `user.displayName` directly it does works but only until you refresh (because when you refresh user goes back to null and then like .2 segs is back to his value)

this is how it looks when I use user before refresh

[image]

since user brings both name and lastname (displayName, basically) I wanted to split it and all the user information is in a document :

```
    const [tempName, setTempName] = useState("");
    const [tempLastName, setTempLastName] = useState("");
    const [tempEmail, setTempEmail] = useState("");
    const [tempPhone, setTempPhone] = useState("");
    const [tempIdType, setTempIdType] = useState("");
    const [tempIdTypes, setTempIdTypes] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const userDoc = db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid);
        userDoc.get().then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                const tempData = [];
                const data = doc.data();
                tempData.push(data);
                setTempName(tempData[0].name)
                setTempLastName(tempData[0].lastName)
                setTempEmail(tempData[0].email)
                setTempPhone(tempData[0].phone)
                setTempIdType(tempData[0].id)
                setTempIdTypes(tempData[0].idType)
                setOldPassword(tempData[0].password)
            }
          });
    }, [user])
```

This is how it looks in the firebase

[image: Mock data]

Is that how is suppose to work?

I would have think that `defaultValue` will update to the value you are giving it... Thank you, I didn't find anything related with this on [TextField documentation](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#basic-textfield). All I know is that they add initialized values from the very beginning and not values that get "updated" with time, I just wanted to display the current information of the user in the form.

Comment: Have a look at [controlled mode](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled), `defaultValue` doesn't work on subsequent renders, if you want to control and update the value, use `value` prop.

Comment: Welp that worked lol, so what's the purpose of defaultValue then ? if you can just use placeholders for stuff like "Name" and then use value instead of defaultValue

Comment: Oh nvm if I use value I can't type anything

Comment: You can, see the live demo from the example above I linked you, you need to use both `onChange` and `value` correctly.

Comment: ah yeah sorry had to delete all the temp and just use my original variables. one down 2 more to goooooo. Also thanks for always being around for MUI stuff you always give a good insight and good explanations

Comment: If your form is getting more complex, consider using [`react-hook-form`](https://react-hook-form.com/) to remove boilerplate code.

Comment: define complex? long ? because is long but not hard to understand is very simple tbh

Comment: [`react-hook-form`](https://bundlephobia.com/package/react-hook-form@7.17.4) handles the form state for you so you don't have to keep track of the values manually and can remove all the `setState`/`state` in your code, just specify the `name` attribute and the validation rule, you can skim the docs more examples on there.

Comment: I think I'm fine the only value that I had to "manually" set up was the data from the doc other than that is pretty much straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [controlled mode](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled) example, `defaultValue` doesn't work on subsequent renders, if you want to control and update the value, use `value` prop.

Default value is usually used in [uncontrolled mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) where the value is controlled by the DOM element, not react itself, and the only way to alter it is setup an initial value when it is first mounted. The value of the uncontrolled component can only be accessed (without using ref) when submitting the form or validating the value, if you want to update the state on the fly based on the value as the user types, use controlled mode.

```
value={value}
onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)}
```

> what's the purpose of defaultValue then? if you can just use placeholders for stuff like "Name" and then use value instead of defaultValue

If you use a placeholder, the default value of that `TextField` won't be submitted in the form (probably not what you expect here).

Comment: Also because of the uncontrolled nature, the default value doesn't update when linked with a state variable map. consider:
`productData.map(([key, value]) => (<TextField />))`
here `defaultValue` property doesn't update properly when elements are removed but using just `value` property does